# DNS Amplification attacks

Tags: dns, ddos

I have this question on my homework about DNS Amplification attacks that I am having trouble figuring out.

> In order to implement a DNS amplification attack, the attacker must
>   trigger the creation of a sufficiently large volume of DNS response
>   packets from the intermediary to exceed the capacity of the link to
>   the target organization. Consider an attack where the DNS response
>   packets are 500 bytes in size (ignoring framing overhead). How many of
>   these packets per second must the attacker trigger to flood a target
>   organization using a 0.5-Mbps link? A 2 Mbps link? Or a 10 Mbps link?
>   If the DNS request packet to the intermediary is 60 bytes in size, how
>   much bandwidth does the attacker consumer to send the necessary rate
>   of DNS request packets for each of the three cases?

I know that an amplification attack has to do with converting a small request into a large response.  The information I'm reading in my book doesn't give an exact value of how much they can amplify however, it at one point says "over 4000 bytes" and thats it.  I assume the first part of the question it simply 0.5 MB / 500 bytes = how many packets per second it takes to flood the target, but that seems to simple (new to this topic).  But that might just be me over thinking it.  The second part I assume is just 60 bytes * the answer from the first part for each of the three cases, but I am unsure of the answer for the first part.  Am I overthinking this or do I already have it solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that they are simply divisions.  But you must first understand how the amplification attack works: the attacker makes a request to the intermediary, but spoofs the source address.  The intermediary will then respond to the spoofed source instead of the attacker.

This works only in a couple of conditions:  connectionless protocols (like UDP, ICMP), the intermediary is well connected having lots of available bandwidth, and the responses are much larger than the request packets.  That is the amplification part.  So if the attacker sends a 60 byte response, and in return triggers a 500 byte reply, the attacker will need less bandwidth to overwhelm the network connection of the victim.

Hopefully this is sufficient for you to figure out the rest of the homework.